# React key property error, despite the fact that key is defined

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have the following `ul` in react: (I know that using index is not always the best idea. Just for simplicity)

```
  <ul>
    {project.topics.map((topic, i) =>
      <li key={i}>{topic}</li>
    )}
  </ul>
```

which results in the following warning:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `CvPage`. See .... for more information.
   in projectCard (at cv.js:22)
```

Why does react complain about the key property, despite it being there? The HTML looks like this:

[image: html]

Comment: Are you sure this is the list React is complaining about?
Rendered HTML matters not, `key` is not trasfered to the DOM

Comment: Have you tried using something other than index? Also, complete code samples are way more helpful than excerpts and a screencap.

Comment: Shouldn't it be {project.topics[i]}? What is your expected result btw?

Comment: use `topic.id` or some other unique identifier. you usually never want to use the array index unless there is no other unique identifier for your datum.